# express-http-context npm module doesnt work with express post request

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I setup a traced id in express.js . I used the module express-http-context

```
httpContext.set('traceId', uuid.v4())
```

But when I try to fetch it using `httpContext.get('traceId')` it doesnt seem to work and gives me undefined for POST express request.
It works fine for GET request.
Not sure what is wrong with this

Comment: Please show us the full code so that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: I was able to fix it.. the httpcontext middleware doesnt work if its declared before other middlewares

Comment: Thank you, Monish, this solves my... ehhemm... very similar problem also!!!! Just move the httpContext.middleware down the middleware stack.

Comment: Duplicate question to [http-context-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611335/node-js-express-unable-to-retrieve-value-from-http-context-for-post-and-put-re/55995352#55995352) you can checkout my answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NODE JS- EXPRESS: Unable to retrieve value from HTTP Context for POST and PUT requests while it works for GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611335/node-js-express-unable-to-retrieve-value-from-http-context-for-post-and-put-re)

Comment: This question was answered before you posted the question so ur question is duplicate